# putting a callback uri in a Oauth request

Tags: python, oauth

I am trying to connect my custom API to a OAuth provider. I am at the first step in the OAuthV1.0 workflow which is the request token step.

I am using the python package: requests_oauthlib and while the [tutorial](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth1_workflow.html#signature-types-hmac-most-common-rsa-plaintext) says im doing it right, the oauth provider keeps asking for a callback uri. How do i add a callback uri to my request?

To further clarify the server is using this provider: [pmr2.oauth](https://github.com/PMR/pmr2.oauth), so I have to use OAuthV1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so with OauthV1 its should be like this:

```
>>> client_key = 'client key'
>>> client_secret = 'secret'
>>> callback_uri = 'https://yourhost.com/callback'

>>> # Using OAuth1Session
>>> oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key, client_secret=client_secret, callback_uri=callback_uri)
```

but your doc does not speak of it, i should have [read the source here](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/master/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py#L34)

hope this will help

Comment: I think this is for OAuthV2 I have to use OAuthV1.0 Since that is what the provider uses.

Comment: is it a known provider service ? because with OAuthV1, as you can see, there is nothing to handle the callbackurl/redirect_uri

Comment: yeah its pmr2.oauth, its a plone package for oauth

Comment: ok . I checked the code of requests-oauth i change my previous code to illustrate how it should be ok